# Logic Operators Syntax

Tags: javascript

What is the issue with this statement?

```
function hello(){
  if('a' == 'a'){
    return 'b' == 'b'
  } &&
  if('c' == 'c'){
    return 'd' == 'd'
  }
}
```

Results in "SyntaxError: Unexpected token &&"

Comment: What is the use of the two && after the } ?

Comment: The goal is if the first statement (A) is true, then evaluate B.  If C is true, evaluate D.  If both returns are true, then return true.

Comment: your return would always be true. So, why not `return true` instead. Use `ELSE` for different condition not `&&`.

Comment: Not in the above example, but both the top and bottom ifs can evaluate to true. If I use else, then only one statement will trigger.

Comment: Unfortunately when you use `return` it's not coming back for the rest ;-) Might as well return an array and evaluate each element if that's the case. But the logic of your code betrays common sense quiet frankly.

Comment: even without "return", if(true){true} && true doesn't work either. Each individually result in a boolean, just not sure how to figure out if all are true.

Comment: I believe what you want is `return (expr1 && expr2) && (expr3 && expr4);` where `'a' == 'a'` would replace `expr1` though it is really unclear from the original question and your clarification. Maybe it would be more clear if you just constructed it as an English sentence. I could then help you convert it to JavaScript.

Comment: If condition A is true, then make sure that condition B is true, else move on.  If condition C is true, then make sure than condition D is true, else move on. If condition E is true, then make sure condition F is true, else return False for the entire function.

Comment: From the responses, I have 5 individual functions inside my main functions and then I evaluate them all at the end miniFunc1() && miniFunc2() && miniFunc3...  Does this seem like the best way to go?

Comment: @Scott that means all the mini-functions should ALL evaluate to true for it to be true.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "ensure condition X is true" and "else move on"? I am not certain how these will impact the result of the function.

Comment: @chuckj, by move on, I mean if condition A is false, then I do not care if condition B is true or false, thus return true for this segment. like this pseudocode:  if A then B else TRUE && if C then D else TRUE && if E then F else FALSE.

Comment: @Edper, yes thats the goal. Each mini-segment or function needs to return true for the final result to be true, but not necessarily all conditions to be true. i.e. if condition A above results in false, I do not want the entire function to return false unless condition B is false.

Comment: You can used the ternary operator to express this as `(a ? b : false) && (c ? d : true) && (e ? f : false)`. Because `a ? b : false` is just a obscure way to write `a && b` and `c ? d : true` is just an obscure way to write `c || d`, this can be simplified to `(a && b) && (c || d) && (e && f)` and the redundant parenthesis can be removed to give us `a && b && (c || d) && e && f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last remark, you need many functions and evaluate each to be true:

```
function func1()
{
  if ('a'=='a')
     { return true; }
  else
     { return false; }
}

function func2()
{
  if ('c'=='c')
     { return true; }
  else
     { return false; }
}
```

You could then evaluate like:

```
function hello()
{
  var result = func1() && func2();
}
```

Comment: That is where I am leaning to as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming what you want is to force the expression represented by `'a' == 'a'` and `'c' == 'c'` to execute but only execute the expression `'b' == 'b'` or `'c' == 'c'` if their guards are `true`. You can make this explicit by,

```
function hello() {
    var first = 'a' == 'a' && 'b' == 'b';
    var second = 'c' == 'c' && 'd' == 'd';
    return first && second;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but if 'a' != 'a', I don't want the entire function to return false.  I tried var first = if('a' == 'a'){'b' == 'b'} else { true }, but it looks like you can't have an if statement there.

Comment: This is exactly what `'a' == 'a' && 'b' == 'b'` does. If `'a' == 'a'` is false it doesn't evaluate `'b' == 'b'`. However, I am still very unclear about what you want so my answer is just a guess.

Comment: Like I said, thank you. But since you are using return first && second, that essentially means that conditions a,b,c,and d all have to be true.

Comment: Your original can be roughly translated to `(a ? b : false) && (c ? d : false)` which is equivalent to `a && b && c && d` which is why the above will require all to be true. On the other hand, if you meant `(a ? b : true) && (c ? d : true)` then this would be `(a || b) && (c || d)`. I recommend you decide on the truth table you want and come up with the right Boolean expression to produce it. It is very difficult for me to tell what you really mean because the original example doesn't make sense to me or the interpreter.